# App fails when compiles shader on Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-ndk, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

App fails on compile shader on Nexus 7 and Nexus 5, but everything works ok on galaxy s3.
Here is shader that is not compiling.

```
#define FRAGMENT_SHADER
#ifdef VERTEX_SHADER
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( atbCoord.x, atbCoord.y, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
#endif
#ifdef FRAGMENT_SHADER
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
#endif
```

I am using GLSurfaceView and OpenGL ES 2.

What can be wrong with this shader?

Comment: Are you sure this is whole code? Where is `atbCoord` declared?
What error do you get?

Also, according to paragraph `4.5.3 Default Precision Qualifiers` of ES 2.0 GLSL specs you must specify default `float` precision for fragment shader. This requirement is often ignored by some OpenGL ES drivers - some may compile such invalid shaders and some may fail.


Link to specs: http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf

Comment: It's not uncommon for code to compile on one device but not another.  As @keaukraine noted, this is usually because one device is too lenient, accepting code that should not be allowed.

Comment: This is part of code without declarations and defining of Precision that I am generating in runtime from code.
I have already found what was the issue.
Nexus 7 and Nexus 5 GPU shader compiler fails if in last line of source code yo have #endif without any new line symbol('\n') after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody google this.

If shader compilation fails application at runtime on Nexus 5 and Nexus 7 check if you have new line symbol aka **'\n' at the end shader source**, because this maybe the issue. Shader source should have end of line at the end of source code.